# remote: Repository not found after updating oauth token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, oauth, bundler, gemfile

After updating my github Personal Access Token, which I use to authenticate a gem from a private repo, bundler keeps telling me:

```
remote: Repository not found 

fatal: repository 'https://MY_OAUTH_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/me/my_repo.git/' not found
```

The gem is specified in the Gemfile as I have always done, with the commit ref and url (and branch).

I tried deleting the bundler gem cache folder and the gem folder. The token is authorising correctly (it gives 'invalid username' if not).

Bundler is latest version 1.11.2.
bundle / bundle install / bundle update all give the same error

Comment: You had a previous `token` that was working?

Comment: Yes. I regenerate it periodically as a security measure.

Comment: Well it's probably something with **github**, you maybe will have to wait a bit before they activate the new `token`.

Comment: It used to activate immediately I think. I sent a support request to guthub but haven't heard back. This is completely blocking my coding, disastor!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to check the scope on the token to authorise it for repo access.

I found this message very misleading :

"Scopes *limit* access for personal tokens. They do not grant any additional permission beyond that which the user already has."